# map through and object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, iteration

i want to create an object like this using iteratio:
opts = [{label:1, value:1}, {label:4, value:4}]
the values inside this object are inside an array portArray = [1,4]
I'm writing

```
const portArray = [1,4];
     return {
       portArray.map(value =>
       ({ label: value value: value }))
     };
   });
```

but it does not seem to work. I'm missing something but i dont know what. Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a comma. `({ label: value value: value }))` should be `({ label: value, value: value }))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is quite confusing, but I think I got the point of your question. Since `map` returns a new array, assuming you have this array: `var portArray = [1,4];` you can use map like this:

```
function manipulateArray(data) {
  return data.map((value) => {
    return {label: value, value: value};
  }
}

var newArray = manipulateArray(portArray);
```

This way `newArray` will equal `[{label:1, value:1}, {label:4, value:4}]`.

You should probably read map' documentation here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided is not valid. It contains an illegal `return` statement.

You can reach the desired solution with using e.g. `Object.assign`.

```js
const portArray = [1, 4],
      res = portArray.map(v => Object.assign({}, { label: v, value: v }));
      console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is missing comma separating your object properties:

```
{
  label: value, // <-- comma between properties
  value: value
}
```

In addition, `Array#map` will return a new array of containing your values mapped to objects which you can store in a local variable:

```
const portArray = [1,4];
const newArray = portArray.map(value =>({ label: value, value: value }));
            // remember this comma :) ----------------^
```

---

***Side note about implicit vs explicit return value for arrow functions:***

*Parenthesis around the object literal following the arrow function, they are necessary so that function's body expression is returned implicitly.*

*Use of explicit return statement in arrow function (notice the addition of curly braces around the function body):*

```
const newArray = portArray.map(value => {
  return {
    label: value,
    value: value 
  }
};
```